# How to know which header declare the specified function by Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Such I have such code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> values = { 5,3,4,6 };
    sort(values.begin(), values.end(), less<>());
    for_each(values.begin(), values.end(), [](int i) {cout << i <<endl; });
    return 0;
    }
```

I want to know which header included by me(`iostream`, `vector` or `algorithm`) have declared the function `less`. Of course, we can use *Google* to search it. But I mean, I want to know this information just by *Visual Studio* . It is possible? I don't know how to do. And I can button the `F12` to know `less` is in header `xstddef`, but I don't know which header(`iostream`, `vector` or `algorithm`) include `xstddef` still. Can anybody can tell me something?

---

ps: Actually I know the `less` in the header of `<functional>`. But note my code have not `#include<functional>`. But it also can run normally. I think must one of this [three header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGjoi.png) include it already. But I don't know which it is

Comment: It's from the `std` namespace.

Comment: In VS everything shall become visible through the right-click, which is technically the alternate-click but no one calls it that.

Comment: Nicely presented question, I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: @BadMiscuit Of course I know, I mean which header include it..

Comment: @Bathsheba Hi, you can not find the `header` this time by your right-click method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **show includes** flag to see which file included each of the included headers

Comment: First time to know **show includes**. Are you in *Visual Studio*?

Comment: @Make I don't understand your question

Comment: I know your mean now

Answer (score 1):

Your first job is to remove `using namespace std;`. Then the use of the C++ Standard Library function `std::less` is obvious at the point of use.

You can then consult your favourite C++ Standard reference manual for the required `#include`s. Using `std::less` requires you to `#include <functional>`.

The fact that you haven't included that file means that you are relying on other headers to include it. Strictly speaking that means you have not written portable C++.

In Visual Studio you can hunt down functions on a right click. But be prepared to wait for a while, and also note that they might not appear where the C++ standard says they should be: so long as you can reach `std::less` by including `<functional>`, an implementation can put the function pretty much wherever it wants.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less

Comment: I don't care it is in which namespace, I just want to know which header it is in. Then I can `#include` that header to use this function. I don't sure you have understadn me. Sorry my poor English. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Make: What I'm saying is that you need to include the header that the reference manual says you should use. In this case it's <functional>.

Comment: Note [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBZuu.png), I don't need to `#include<functional>`. I can run the code normally.

Comment: I give up. Yes, you can sometimes. But for portable C++ you need to #include<funtional>

Comment: This is why I ask this question. I think must one of this [three header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGjoi.png) include it already. But I don't know which it is..